# How can I re-use proto-buffer messages for different gRPC endpoints?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a Go application that uses proto-buffers (Proto3 to be precise).

This application has 2 endpoints, `A` and `B` defined as follows:

```
rpc A(ARequest) returns (AResponse) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
    post: "/someURLA"
    body: "*"
  };
}
rpc B(BRequest) returns (BResponse) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
    put: "/someURLB"
    body: "*"
  };
}
```

Here are the messages they use:

```
message ARequest {
    // Blah Blah Blah
}

message BRequest {
    // Blah Blah Blah   
}

message AResponse {
    // Blah Blah Blah
}

message BResponse {
    // Blah Blah Blah   
}
```

Endpoints `A` and `B` actually require the same input format and have the same output format. So `ARequest` is identical to `BRequest` and `AResponse` is identical to `BResponse`. But these duplicative definitions in the protofile are terribly wasteful and might diverge. So I changed it to this:

```
rpc A(AOrBRequest) returns (AOrBResponse) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
    post: "/someURLA"
    body: "*"
  };
}
rpc B(AOrBRequest) returns (AOrBResponse) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
    put: "/someURLB"
    body: "*"
  };
}

message AOrBRequest {
    // Blah Blah Blah
}

message AOrBResponse {
    // Blah Blah Blah
}
```

But when I did, I got these errors during compilation:

```
Name of request type "AOrBRequest" should be "ARequest".
Name of response type "AOrBResponse" should be "AResponse"
Name of request type "AOrBRequest" should be "BRequest".
Name of response type "AOrBResponse" should be "BResponse"
```

So how can I make these two endpoints reuse the same messages for requests and responses?

Comment: There is nothing that requires the method name and message name to be the same, unless you're using custom linters. You likely forgot to change or generate something. Showing exactly what you are running would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [import statements](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#importing_definitions) to reuse message definitions.

> You can use definitions from other .proto files by importing them. To
> import another .proto's definitions, you add an import statement to
> the top of your file:
>
> ```
> import "myproject/other_protos.proto";
> ```

For instance, if you downloaded the Protocol Buffers binary package, the `readme.txt` in the archive says:

> If you intend to use the included well known types then don't forget
> to copy the contents of the `include` directory somewhere as well, for
> example into `/usr/local/include/`.

If you've done that, you can now import (or re-use, as you put it) the Messages defined by Google.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package mypackage;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

service Bla {
    rpc ResetUserPW(UserEmail) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
    rpc ServerTime(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Timestamp) {}
}

message UserEmail {
    string email = 1;
    CallBackUrl url = 2;
}
```

Comment: Is this a valid solution though? I feel like it's odd to make a move all the requests to a diff proto and then import it to re-use it